# Reprogram a Volkswagen key fob with only 1 key?

Tags: vw, key, fob

I bought a 2015 Volkswagen Passat, it came with 2 key fobs and 3 keys. Upon careful inspection, (months later) I noticed one of the key fobs doesn't work with this car, and 2 of the 3 keys don't work; they are cut completely different. I was reading online, an article describing that the key fob could be [reprogrammed](https://itstillruns.com/program-vw-key-fob-7595083.html) to my specific vehicle, but it involves the use of 2 keys, and I only have one.

Is there a way to reprogram my 2nd fob with only 1 key?

Comment: A dealer job probably.

Comment: That or a good locksmith

Comment: Where is @narkeleptk when we need him?

Comment: In UK, the main dealer was *very* expensive, wanted a deposit, and delivery was 2 weeks. The local branch of a key/shoe/sign/photo chain did the job while I waited for less than ¼ what the dealer said. They cloned the single (remote control) key I took them.